# How to align dissimilar numbers with uncertainties in LaTeX table columns with siunitx?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align, siunitx

I am trying to typeset a table with data values and their uncertainties using LaTeX with the siunitx package. Some data values within a given column are much larger than 1, and others are much smaller than 1. The siunitx package first aligns the numbers at their decimal point, and then aligns the data at the "+/-" sign used for the uncertainty.

This two-step alignment is not desired in my situation. I need the data aligned at the "+/-" sign only.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true , table-align-uncertainty=true }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.7(2)] }
\toprule
{Column 2}  & {Column 2} \\
Hello       & 124(5) \\
World       & 0.0005678(9) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,etoolbox}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true , table-align-uncertainty=true }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l S[table-format=3.7,detect-weight,mode=text] @{${}\pm{}$}
S[table-format=1.7,detect-weight,mode=text] }
\toprule
{Column 2}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Column 2} \\
{Hello}       & 124.0000000 & 5 \\
{World }      & 0.0005678 & 0.0000009 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please be aware that this will drastically change the number of significant figures of the entry in the first row.

Comment: If you want to split up the value and its uncertainty into two columns, you could simply use `r @{${}\pm{}$} l` instead of the two `S` type columns.

Comment: Well, I could certainly achieve the right output by manually splitting the value and its uncertainty into two columns. However, that's far from elegant and certainly not convenient. There must be a better way by using the magic of siunitx.